# What would be the best way/format to store data with date as the key

Tags: json, database

I currently store activity/playtime of users in a JSON file in the following format *Date->ID->Time*

```
{ 
"2021-06-5": {
"User1Identifier": 3789,
"User5Identifier": 9889,
"User2Identifier": 3542
}, 
"2021-06-6": {
"User5Identifier": 96408,
"User7Identifier": 3674,
"User3Identifier": 864
}, 
// And so on
}
```

My question is if there is a better way to store this information. I thought about using a MySQL Database, but I'm concerned because I'd have to store the current date with every entry meaning I would end up with a lot more data (Every user would have the following table [ ID | Time | Date ])
Which to me seems less efficient to me. Would you recommend switching to a database, or do you have a better idea as to how I should store the data?

Info: I handle/use this data in both PHP and C# if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is related to the structuring and relation of data.
First thing that comes to mind when I read your question is MongoDB, specifically unstructured database where the database or 'Store' is not conserned with how the data relate.

I'd recomend reading about MongoDB and MQL which is a query language specifically for unstrictured datasets.

https://www.quest.com/community/blogs/b/database-management/posts/how-to-work-with-data-using-mongodb-query-language

This approach is common in handling unstructured data and saves memory and gives more flexibiliy if your data is distributed in multiple locations.

Another way would be to mplement a serialization/deserialization module that parse your data and load it into:
IList<Dictionary<string, IList>> and not even use any DB for that matter - I wouldn't recomend this way because It'll clutter your code and force you to handle lookups and caching which I'm sure there are plenty of opensource libs that do that for you.